# How to log successful and failed authentication for both local and AD users in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, audit-trail

Was following the guide here https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-2131 and managed to verify that it is working for default "Jenkins’ own user database" security realm. However, this doesnt work for "LDAP" security realm.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Edit: Ok it is working for domain accounts. i.e. logged in: {username} and logged out: {username}.

However for any failed authentication, it is not showing any username (both local and domain users) i.e. Audit request /loginError by user NA from {ip address}

Can't find any relevant information on it. What could fix it?

Comment: I suppose you need to examine the system logs for the class which is logging the authentication message and then setup a [custom logger](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204880580-How-do-I-create-a-logger-in-Jenkins-for-troubleshooting-and-diagnostic-information-).

Comment: Ok it is working for domain accounts. i.e. logged in: <username> and logged out: <username>.

However for any failed authentication, it is not showing any username (both local and domain users) i.e. Audit request /loginError by user NA from <ip address>

Can't find any relevant information on it. Do you happen to know the fix?

Comment: Don't use LDAP (we use AD), but I'd imagine this is it:: [`LOGGER.log(hadSuccessfulAuthentication? Level.FINE : Level.WARNING; "Failed to bind to LDAP: userDn"+userDn+"  username="+username,cause)`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ldap-plugin/blob/94fe2df805fe7daba02d432581aa2f625bc2e2cb/src/main/java/jenkins/security/plugins/ldap/BindAuthenticator2.java#L57). Try set up a simple instance just w/LDAP pluginand login success, logout, bad login (user), ad login (password), and see what appears in the Jenkins logs.